# How could I mix the CONTAINS with the other conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Would you kindly let me know how could I combine CONTAINS with the other conditions in SQL? What I want to do is I have a search field in my website and I want to narrow the result with the other options. For example if somebody search for shirt the result page will shows all data has the word of "shirt" using CONTAINS in my SQL code. After that I there are some options like color, size etc. which has to narrow the search of shirt. Here is when first pose:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'shirt') AND color LIKE '%' AND size LIKE '%'
```

So far is fine and its working. But what if our user dont use the search field and they come directly to for example color? What should my query looks like?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE contains(*, '???') AND color LIKE 'Red' AND size LIKE '%'
```

Basically in LIKE condition when you use '%' means everything, but honesty I dont know how to deal with contains???
This is what I'm thinking. Please let me know if this should be handled in any other way. By the way I'm using SQL 2008 and classic ASP.

Thanks in advance for your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Usually what you would do is modify the query form to only contain the appropriate predicates. So the two queries above would instead be writtedn as

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'shirt')

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE color like 'Red'
```

If it is really necessary to use a static query form then you can consider a more complicated version that takes into account the 'empty condition'.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
    WHERE ('???' = 'shirt' OR CONTAINS(*, 'shirt')) 
    AND ('%' = '%' OR color like '%') 
    AND ('%' = '%' OR size like '%')
```

Note, it looks strange above because this query is not parameterized. So you have a query that ends up executing with constants equaling each other. Better still would be to use parameterization, because it helps prevent sql injection attacks and can be more performant.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
    WHERE ('???' = @containsParam OR CONTAINS(*, @containsParam)) 
    AND ('%' = @colorParam OR color like @colorParam) 
    AND ('%' = @sizeParam OR size like @sizeParam)
```

Comment: Peter, unfortunately this not working for me because my code is more complex and joining couple of tables as well and I cannot add the '%' = @param to all of them. This might slow the process. Is there any way else?

Comment: If you're talking about slowing the process of coding, then you should consider the cost of original development is actually very small for almost any project. If you think it will slow down the execution, I'd ask you to profile your queries and measure them. All optimizers I'm aware of (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL) will actually do better with this query form because the constants can be easily evaluated and eliminate that part of the predicate. It should be faster than your query above when some default parameters are supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your website so it dynamically produces different queries when different text boxes left empty, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'shirt')
                           --- leaving these out
                           --- AND color LIKE '%' AND size LIKE '%'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE color LIKE 'Red' 
                           --- leaving these out
                           --- AND CONTAINS(*, '???') 
                           --- AND size LIKE '%'
```

or, and only if all boxes are selected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'shirt')
  AND color LIKE 'Red' 
  AND size LIKE 'Large'
```